# Progressbar for android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked

Tags: android, progress-bar

I am using sqlite database to return list of data using android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, I want it to be in a way that when i click on the check item the progress bar shows up counting from 1-100%.
Is there a way to show it when the item is clicked
This is my code:

```
 mydb = new DBHelper(this);
        ArrayList array_list = mydb.getAllItems();
        ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, array_list);
        mRecyclerview =(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.items_List);
        obj = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        obj.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        obj.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        //Take a countdown timer///
        //Then inside that countdown timer create a progress dialog.

    }
});
```